# Labeling with comma as in QGIS Attributes table

Tags: qgis, point, labeling, building, floating

In QGIS 3.22 I would like to label an area with decimal values. In the attribute table, the values are displayed separated by commas, but the areas are labelled separated by periods. Please help!
Stefan

[image: attributes table]

[image: result in map]

After converting to string and replacing `"."` with `","`

[image]

Comment: What is the data type of the column?

Comment: data type is real

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 5):

If you have QGIS 3.28 or newer, you can use this expression to remove the thousand separator:**

```sql
format_number("Area", places:=1, omit_group_separators:=true)
```

[image]

---

You need to use the [`format_number`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#format-number) function as your label expression:

```sql
format_number("Area", places:=1)
```

It will format your real value to a string using your locale formatting (comma vs period separator).

The locale can be changed (overridden) in `Options > General > Override System Locale > Locale`

you can also directly override the locale in the expression:

format_number("Area", places:=1, language:='fr')

[image]

[image]

Comment: this works. thx.
but...
a locale separator for thousands like "space" or "." is now generated in between,
eg 1 250,2 or 1.250,2
is there a way to get it this way > 1250,2?

Comment: There seem to be issues with format_number() since I can't seem to be able to remove the space thousand separator for some reason. And it shouldn't show up at all since I have unchecked the "Show group (thousand) separator" in the "Override System Locale" settings

Comment: there seems to be no solution concerning this problem.
i've tried to enable "Show group (thousand) separator" in the "Override System Locale" settings with no positive effect.

Comment: I have created an issue on the QGIS GitHub if you would like to see if anything changes or if we missed something https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/55972

Comment: ok :) i'll check

Comment: Well, I'd missed something, I updated the answer.

Comment: ok, thx. but we use v3.22...